# Cocos2D - Communicating between layers

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, layer, scene

Im here to ask a kind of noobish question, Im learning to roll with cocos2d.

My question is, whats the best way(and how) to communicate between layers with a scene?

For example.

I've got a Layer where I've got a sprite with a button, there's a layer with a string.

Everytime I click the button the string is supposed to go +1. (So if You click 3 times, the string would be equal to 3.)

I've got it like this:

Scene.m

```
-(id)init {
self = [super init];
if(self != nil){
    //button Layer
    buttonLayer *buttonLayer = [buttonLayer node];
    [self addChild:buttonLayer z:0];

    //Gameplay Layer :D

    stringLayer *numberStringLayer = [stringLayer node];
    [self addChild:numberStringLayer z:2];
    }
}
```

buttonLayer.m

```
-(id)init {
int xPosition = 385;
int yPosition = 75;


_button = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"button.png"
                                 selectedImage:@"button.png"
                                        target:self selector:@selector(checkButton:)];
_button.tag =0;


_button.position = ccp(xPosition,yPosition);


_buttonMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:_button, nil];
_buttonMenu.position = CGPointZero;
[self addChild:_buttonMenu];
}



 -(void)checkButton:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"Button Pressed");

  buttonPressedCount =+;

 //Here goes algorithm that interacts with scene/layer
}
```

stringLayer.m

```
-(id)init {

self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {



    _numberString = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:18.0];
    _numberString.color = ccc3(0,0,0);
    _numberString.position = ccp(125,300);
    [self addChild:_numberString];
}

return self;
```

}

```
 -(void)updateStringWithNumber:(int)tempNumb {
_numberString.string = tempNumb; //or something like that....
   }
```

So...where/how do I cast the variables and how/where do I access/call them?

Thanks for your time! :D Have an excelent day!

Comment: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/files/cocos2d-essential-reference-sample/Strategies_for_Accessing_Other_Nodes.html

Comment: Which of those options would You choose?

            UILayer *tempLayer = [scene sharedGameScene].stringLayer;
            [tempLayer updateString];
??? If so, where/how do I cast it?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I tried doing getting ChildBy Tag but I simply didn't know how to. Tried this on scene.m "stringLayer *numberStringLayer = [stringLayer node];
    [self addChild:numberStringLayer z:2 tag:113];"

and this when the user presses the button:
" CCNode *otherNode = [stringLayer.parent_ getChildByTag:113];
            
            [otherNode updateLabel];"

Answer (score 0):

Both button and label needs to be controlled by someone for the interaction you desire so it will be logical to implement the button pressed event in the controlling object which in your case is the scene object (I'll recommend you have a main layer rather then a scene as it will make managing other layers easier if you'll need to)

So one option will be to pass the scene as the target for the button pressed event. The scene will implement the button pressed method and can easily modify the label as needed as you have a direct access to it in the scene object.

So your button layer init method might change to :

```
-(id)initWithTarget:(id)btnTtarget {
.
.
_button = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"button.png"
                                 selectedImage:@"button.png"
                                        target:btnTtarget  selector:@selector(checkButton:)];
.
.
}
```

And in your scene create the button layer using this init method.
Make sure your scene implements the selector `btnTtarget` and now you can easily access and call method on the label layer.